# Firebase Performance View Sessions shows no sessions

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

I am trying to integrate my Android app with the Firebase Performance Monitoring as per the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-android?authuser=0).

I am seeing data being reported in the console, but I am always seeing "0 sessions". When I tap on "View Sessions", I just get a generic message saying I need to upgrade my SDK.

I am using `'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:20.0.1'`.

Am I missing something?

[image: 0 sessions]

[image]

Comment: Were you able to find solution ... I don't use any remote config as in the only answer

Answer (score 0):

Check your remote config if you are using it, and create more scenarios for performance to listen to as the device isn't triggering it correctly.

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/app-start-foreground-background-traces?authuser=0#more-detail-trace-samples

Answer (score 0):

Did you generate 100 samples or more? I found this Github comment explaining that the sample rate is 1% so you need to have at least 100 samples for sessions to show up: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/10799#issuecomment-1424141052

Comment: This awnser should be a comment on the post, not an answer.